# When extending a layout all the @yield are rendered instead of the @sections chosen

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

When trying to use @yield and @section it does not work. With only extending the layout, all the layout is rendered, I can't choose with @section and @endsection what will be rendered.

This is for a Laravel project with HomeStead on my local machine

plantilla.blade.php is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            @yield('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')

            This is another container
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the contact.blade.php is:

```
@extends("layouts.plantilla")

@section('content')

@endsection
```

When opening contact.blade.php, both sections are displayed (sidebar AND content), instead of only content, which is the section I'm actually calling.

This happens also if I just leave the first line (@extends("layouts.plantilla")
without calling any section, it will render all of its content

What could am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are yielding both `content` and `sidebar` inside your `div` already, so the "*This is the master sidebar*" and "*This is another container*" will always show, even if you don't use that section.

You need to change your code in main layout like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       @yield('sidebar')
       @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

So now, if you only want to display a content of your page, you do it like this:

```
@extends("layouts.plantilla")

   @section('content')
      <div class="container">
        This is another container
    </div>
   @endsection
```